# How can I take this image on the same line as my text?

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, posters

**Problem**

I have a sentence in my document that is all on one line. I also have a logo (as a .eps file) that is about the same height as the text. I would like to have the logo on the same line as the text, as if it were a kind of bullet-point.

**Notes**

I am making a poster using a template, where figures have been defined in some weird (to me at least) way.

**Minimal working example**

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% POSTER DEFINITION
\newenvironment{poster}{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95\textwidth}}
{\end{minipage} 
\end{center}}

% FIGURE DEFINITION
\newcommand{\myfig}[3][0]{
\begin{center}
\vspace{1.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=#3\hsize,angle=#1]{#2}
\nobreak\medskip
\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}

\vspace{2cm}
\myfig[0]{Time.eps}{0.01}
\large{Here is some text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text.}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try just using `\includegraphics{Time.eps}` directly instead of that `\myfig` tag?

Comment: @Thruston that worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you have the center environment as part of your definition? I got decent results with this:

```
% FIGURE DEFINITION
\newcommand{\myfig}[3][0]{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=#3\hsize,angle=#1]{#2}
}
```

Then you can either use

```
\myfig[0]{time}{0.01} {\Large Text...........}
```

or

```
\myfig[0]{time}{0.01}~{\Large Text...........}
```

if for some reason you're worried about a line break between your text and your graphic bullet.